# What is meant by 73 hour birth

Tags: human-biology

I was reading an article, when I read a sentence saying, **His mother ... nearly died less than three years later during Mathers' 73-hour birth.**

What does mean by 73-hour birth?

Comment: This isn't really a Biology question, it just means that Mathers took 73 hours to be born.  If you need further explanation, I'd suggest trying English Language Learners http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about use of the English Language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find that topic related to [Eminem's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminem) mother, Debbie Mathers-Briggs, who almost died delivering her first son(Eminem) at the end of a 73-hour labor or 73-hour birth. That "73 hour birth" means she was in labor(to undergo the efforts of childbirth) for "73 hours".

Comment: yah, anyone can find that article by reading `Mathers` :D and yes, thanks for the answer :)